# How to preserve any new xml keys when deserializing an XML string to a class, modify some values then reserialize

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

Here is an example code of my issue.

```vb
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(TypeName:="Person")>
Public Class clsXMLtest
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String
End Class

Dim x As clsXMLtest
Dim s1 As String = "<Person>
                      <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
                      <LastName>Hill</LastName>
                   </Person>"
Dim xmlSer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(clsXMLtest))
x = CType(xmlSer.Deserialize(New IO.StringReader(s1)), clsXMLtest)
x.LastName = "Pike"
Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter
xmlSer.Serialize(sw, x)
Dim s2 As String = sw.ToString


Dim s3 As String = "<Person>
                      <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
                      <LastName>Hill</LastName>
                      <NewKey>NEW</NewKey>
                   </Person>"
x = CType(xmlSer.Deserialize(New IO.StringReader(s3)), clsXMLtest)
x.LastName = "Jack"
sw = New IO.StringWriter
xmlSer.Serialize(sw, x)
Dim s4 As String = sw.ToString
```

The final output no longer contains the new key NewKey
How to preserve any new keys added to the original XML?

Comment: The property doesn't exist in `clsXMLTest` (I guess, please provide the definition) so you can't serialize it. `How to preserve any new keys added to the original XML?` that's not how it works. By declaring the serializer like this `New XmlSerializer(GetType(clsXMLtest))` it only knows about the properties in that class.

Comment: That is the point, the XML key <NewKey> is being added to the XML string at a later date, (by other processes). But, whenever "old" code access this XML, the new setting is lost.

Comment: So add the property to the class definition. This `xmlSer.Serialize(sw, x)` is still using `New XmlSerializer(GetType(clsXMLtest))` so it only knows how to serialize properties described in `clsXMLtest`. What does `x` look after deserialization the second time? Can you see that property? Of course not because 1. it's not defined, 2. it wouldn't know what type to assign `<NewKey>NEW</NewKey>` to with no definition.

Comment: You have a round peg, square peg, and round hole. The round peg fits through the round hole, and the square peg is discarded.

Comment: To allow for this, instead of adding totally new elements to the xml, you should have some sort of collection of elements with a Name/Value pair in it. Then you can add as many as you like and serialization will accept them into a List.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [XmlAnyElementAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute):

```
class Person
{
    ...

    // Apply the XmlAnyElementAttribute to a field
    // returning an array of XmlElement objects.
    // XmlSerializer will put all unknown elements here
    // on deserialization, and serialize them back.
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XmlElement[] AllElements ;
}
```

Comment: Awesome This is exactly it.   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElement()>

Answer (score 0):

I would change the class to this, adding a new property which is a `List(Of NewElement)`

```vb
<XmlRoot("Person")>
Public Class clsXMLtest
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property FirstName As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property LastName As String
    <XmlElement("NewElement")>
    Public Property NewElements As List(Of NewElement)
End Class

Public Class NewElement
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property Name As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

To deserialize

```vb
Dim s3 As String = "<Person>
                        <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Hill</LastName>
                        <NewElement Name=""NewKey"" Value=""NEW""/>
                        <NewElement Name=""OtherKey"" Value=""OTHER""/>
                    </Person>"
x = CType(xmlSer.Deserialize(New IO.StringReader(s3)), clsXMLtest)
```

Comment: You are correct about s3.   I understand your idea about creating a ListOf, it will work.  The disadvantage is, the  code will not be able to be updated to to have a Strong type for the new setting.  ie  Public NewKey as string

Comment: hehe Fixed, Thanks

Comment: Right, of course. But you had started with *no* definition in the class for the new property at all, so this is at least a minor improvement. You can always cast later i.e. `Dim i As Integer = Integer.Parse(x.NewElements.Where(Function(e) e.Name = "ID").Single())`